# Inactivate Controls within Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, style, hold, interactive

Given a certain `Control` object (checkbox, for example) within a `Manipulate` environment, my goal is to define another control which is inactivated if the first control is active (or satisfies some condition). How do I do this efficiently? Are there built in functions to help me do this?

A first idea was to simply create an `If` condition within a `Dynamic@Grid` in the `Control` panel, as follows

```
Manipulate[b,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"a", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]},
    If[a == 0,
     {"b", Control[{{b, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]},
     b = 0;
     {Style["b", Gray], Control[{{b0, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}
     ]},
 Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

which gives

[image]

[image]

Here I'm creating a null control `b0` to replace `b` and setting `b = 0` for convenience.

This not bad, but I would like to check if any of the following are possible:

1. Add a `Gray` tone to checkbox `b` whenever it's inactive;
2. Make it impossible to interact with checkbox `b` if inactive, that is, lock the dependent control in a specific state;
3. Find an efficient way to do this for multiple controls and dependencies, and avoid creating null controls as mentioned (for example, maybe I could simply define a function that toggles `st` in `Style["b",st]`, for `st = Black` or `st = Gray`, and force `b = False` when `a = 1`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Dynamic[a == 0]` as the option setting for [`Enabled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Enabled.html) in the second control:

```
Manipulate[b, 
 {{a, 0, "a"}, {1, 0}},
 {{b, 0, "b"}, {1, 0}, Enabled -> Dynamic[a == 0]}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

If you need to fade the label when the control is not enabled:

```
Manipulate[b, 
  {{a, 0, "a"}, {1, 0}}, 
  {{b, 0, Dynamic[If[a == 0, "b", Style["b", GrayLevel[.7]]]]}, {1, 0}, 
     Enabled -> Dynamic[a == 0]}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

If the second control is a slider, that is, if you use

```
 {b, 0, Dynamic[If[a == 0, "b", Style["b", GrayLevel[.7]]]]}, 0, 1, 
    Enabled -> Dynamic[a == 0]}
```

for the second control, you get

[image]

**Update:** An alternative approach is to use the option [`TrackingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html) in the first control to update all dynamic variables that depend on `a`:

```
Manipulate[b, 
 {{a, 0, "a"}, {1, 0}, TrackingFunction -> 
    (a = #; b = (1 - a) b; benabled = a == 0; 
     sty = (a /. {0 -> Black, 1 -> GrayLevel[.8]}); &)}, 
 {{b, 0, Dynamic@Style["b", sty]}, {1, 0}, Enabled -> Dynamic[benabled]}, 
 {{benabled, True}, None}, 
 {{sty, Black}, None}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: Can I set `b = 0` when `a = 1` in your first solution?

Comment: @sam, maybe  replace `b` in the first argument of `Manipulate` with `Dynamic[b = (1 - a) b]`?

Comment: I can incorporate it in the `If` you have on your second code, and that's actually even better. Didn't know about the `Enabled` option. This is great, thanks!

Comment: It's even better if I define `If[a == 1,  b = 0; sty = Gray,  sty = Black];` right after `Dynamic@Grid[{`, and simply have `Style["b",sty]` in the control. This helps me to change a lot of widget dependencies easier.